# Android writing test for Button

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

How do i write a test that makes sure a button has been initialized and has an onClickListener tied to it?

My code does not work obviously, the getOnClickListener cannot be found on the object, what should i use instead?

```
    public class LunchListTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LunchList> {

        ........

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception{
        super.setUp();
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
        mActivity = getActivity();
        mSaveButton = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.save); 

    }

    public void testPreConditions(){

            assertTrue("Save button does not listen to clicks", mSaveButton.getOnClickListener() );
    }
```

Comment: u need to set onClick lister in button...

Comment: Thats done in the activity, I am asking for how to check, not how to set!

Comment: u mean if click event is there in button or not ??

Comment: "has an onClickListener tied to it" YES

Comment: ok, u hv added click listerner in xml or from code?

Comment: come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34961/m-t-e-t-n-o

Comment: Monica please see my own answer below, and clean up comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct method for usage here is "hasOnClickListener" :

```
 mSaveButton.hasOnClickListeners()
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to sub-class Button, and store a boolean value - default false to become true when you call `setOnClickListener(..);`